# Converting string to dictionary python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, newline

I created a file and there is a dictionary.
Now I want that dictionary from the file but I do not want in string and I don't want the newline character.
I obtained something like this:

```
"{'Greennhouse 1': {'Product': '4', 'Location of greenhouse': '2',
'Unities of the product': 6, 'Designation': '1', 'Growth state of the
product': '5', 'Code of wsn': 1, 'Area of greenhouse': 3}}\n"
```

But I want this:

```
{'Greennhouse 1': {'Product': '4', 'Location of greenhouse': '2',
'Unities of the product': 6, 'Designation': '1', 'Growth state of the
product': '5', 'Code of wsn': 1, 'Area of greenhouse': 3}}
```

Comment: what did you try? How does your file look like?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/converting-a-string-to-dictionary

Comment: I try using dict, with something I saw here, but it didn't work, because I have a dictionary in another dictionary, I guess. I thought of creating a new dictionary and putting the elements there, but I don't now how to take the str...

Comment: Given the description in the question, [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)is clearly the way to go.

Comment: @SaicharanSM I actually have seen that, but I wanted to avoid any other imports (because I already have a lot).

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I will probably use that, but do I have to import ast?

Comment: @Diana `ast` is a standard module -- it should be available on any (decently recent) standard installation of Python. You only have to add `import ast` to use it.

Answer (score 4):

The [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function is designed to convert Python literal expressions represented as a string, into actual Python data structures. So:

```
import ast

dictionary = ast.literal_eval(string)
```

The presence of the `\n` newline character in the input will be of no consequence.

Comment: I use that and it worked. But now I can't get values from the dictionary... What should I do? I already try by creating a new dictionary, using the get(), but nothing works...

Comment: @DianaVasconcelosFerreira: It's unclear what you mean by "it worked" and then you say that you can't get values from the dictionary. If you continue to have trouble, I suggest opening a new question for the next problem you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

although better `ast.literal_eval` use, depending on the circumstances may be used `exec`, who interprete all code into a string

```
s = "{'Greennhouse 1': {'Product': '4', 'Location of greenhouse': '2', 'Unities of the product': 6, 'Designation': '1', 'Growth state of the product': '5', 'Code of wsn': 1, 'Area of greenhouse': 3}}\n"
s = "d=" + s
exec s
print d
```

Comment: Using `exec` is terrible advice here.

Comment: @GregHewgill why? could you tell me why ?

Comment: (1) Using `exec` exposes your code to injection or DoS attacks when the input is from some external source. (2) Using `exec` requires another variable (`d`) which even using the general `eval` would avoid. (3) Using `exec` within a function can severely impact the performance, because its presence disables many optimisations that the compiler can do.

Comment: @GregHewgill (1) it depends on the use of the script if it is for personal use there is no problem, sometimes don't be paranoid (2) why? do not give a reason (3) this is true, but sometimes the performance isn't the most important .....

Comment: (4) There is a much better alternative for this purpose (`ast.literal_eval`).

Comment: @GregHewgill (4) you are right .... is better `ast.literal_eval` .... but .... it isn't my answer "terrible advice"

Comment: Then I would suggest changing "should" in your answer to "can". There is no reason to choose `exec` over any of the other choices presented in the answers here.

Comment: @GregHewgill you are right .... english problem .... I confuse may, can , could, might, and must ..... in my native language they are similar

Comment: No worries. I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.

Comment: @peterh done, add better explanation

Answer (score 0):

to get your dictionnary from a file as the way you want you have to save it like an object you can use pickle from python standard library

```
import pickle
mydic = {'Greennhouse 1': {'Product': '4', 'Location of greenhouse': '2',
       'Unities of the product': 6, 'Designation': '1', 'Growth state of the
        product': '5', 'Code of wsn': 1, 'Area of greenhouse': 3}}
with open("mydic.dic","wb") as f :
    pickle.dump(mydic,f)
# later in code
with open("mydic.dic","rb") as f :
    mynewdic = pickle.load(f)
    print mynewdic
```